# what is difference between these two

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have checkboxes in my view for filtering the data i have two different fileds implemented like this in my ListAPIView what's the difference between field 1 and field_2

```
field_1 = request.GET.get('field_1', 'true') == 'true'
field_2 = request.GET.get('field_1', False)
```

Comment: In both conditions `request.GET.get('field_1', 'default_val')` the 2nd parameter will return some default value if form variable is unset. field_1 is defaulting to string 'true' if nothing has selected in form then comparing it with string 'true' and based on that it will assign True or False. field_2 is getting some boolean value from your form and if nothing is selected it will default to False and assign back to your variable.

Comment: @k33da_the_bug Thanks for the reply bro here i have another checkbox field to filter the data can i consider request.GET.get('field_3', False)

Comment: **field_1** will return you a boolean value if condition is satisfied it will return *True* else *Flase*